# Autodesk Design Automation API DWG to PDF using Dropbox

Tags: dropbox-api, autodesk-forge, autodesk-designautomation

Hello I am struggling with finding a working example on how to convert a DWG file to a PDF file. I am using Autodesk Design Automation API and Dropbox. I try to use following command to place a WorkItem

```
{
"Arguments":{
"InputArguments":[
   {
      "Resource": "https://content.dropboxapi.com/2/files/download",
      "Name": "HostDwg",
      "Headers":[
        {
         "Name":"Authorization",
         "Value":"Bearer xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"

        },{
          "Name":"Dropbox-API-Arg",
          "Value" : {"path":"/original.dwg"}

        }
        ]
   }
],
"OutputArguments":[
   {
      "Name": "Result",
      "HttpVerb": "PUT",
      "Resource": "https://content.dropboxapi.com/2/files/upload",
      "StorageProvider": "Generic",
      "Headers":[
        {
         "Name":"Authorization",
         "Value":"Bearer xxxxxxxxxxxxxx"

        },{
         "Name":"Dropbox-API-Arg",
         "Value": {"path":"/test.pdf"}   

        }

                                    ]

   }
                                          ]
                  },   "ActivityId": "PlotToPDF","Id": ""}
```

Unfortunately I get following Error message

```
An unexpected 'StartObject' node was found for property named 'Value' when reading from the JSON reader. A 'PrimitiveValue' node was expected.
```

I think it has to do with the second Header I have defined, to specify the file to be downloaded or uploaded. It is unclear to me how to set this value correct.
If Iam using dropbox api without Design Automation API this is working. I can define a Header named Dropbox-API-Arg and define to download/upload path.

Any help would be appreciated. Thankyou

Comment: My colleagues shared some comments as below. As to 'download Dropbox file by 'https://content.dropboxapi.com/2/files/download', instead of by 'direct downloading', we are discussing further with engineer team. With my test, Design Automation downloaded the dataset with correct size, but it did not identify which file format, so caused the failure of launching AcCoreConsole.

Comment: Thankyou for updating this. It is working expect using /download and Dropbox-API-Arg. I will leave the case open until this is clarified.

Comment: Hi, as @Albert Szilvasy mentioned, the download is also working now. I confirmed by my test harness.  Could you check if it works at your side?

Comment: Yes it is working. Thankyou

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have improved Design Automation so that now using `Dropbox-API-Arg` header works both for upload and download. The following will convert a DWG to PDF in your dropbox account:

```
{
  "Arguments": {
    "InputArguments": [
      {
        "Resource": "https://content.dropboxapi.com/2/files/download",
        "Name": "HostDwg",
        "Headers" : [
          {
            "Name" : "Authorization",
            "Value" : "Bearer ..."
          },
          {
            "Name" : "Dropbox-API-Arg",
            "Value" : "{\"path\":\"/test/test.dwg\"}"
          }
          ]
      }
    ],
    "OutputArguments": [
      {
        "Name": "Result",
        "HttpVerb": "POST",
        "Resource": "https://content.dropboxapi.com/2/files/upload",
        "Headers" : [
          {
            "Name" : "Authorization",
            "Value" : "Bearer ..."
          },
          {
              "Name" : "Content-Type",
              "Value" : "application/octet-stream"
          },
          {
            "Name" : "Dropbox-API-Arg",
            "Value" : "{\"path\":\"/test/test.pdf\", \"mode\":\"add\"}"
          }
          ]
      }
    ]
  },
  "ActivityId": "PlotToPDF"
}
```

Comment: Thankyou it is working now. Great Job. Have you tried if it works also when defining RelatedFiles? E.g. define a .shx File that is also in dropbox and try downloading both files from /download?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that we expect "Value" to be string and you are passing an object. Here's a working example:

```
{
  "Arguments": {
    "InputArguments": [
      {
        "Resource": "http://download.autodesk.com/us/samplefiles/acad/blocks_and_tables_-_imperial.dwg",
        "Name": "HostDwg"
      }
    ],
    "OutputArguments": [
      {
        "Name": "Result",
        "HttpVerb": "POST",
        "Resource": "https://content.dropboxapi.com/2/files/upload",
        "Headers" : [
            {
                "Name" : "Authorization",
                "Value" : "Bearer ..."
            },
            {
                "Name":"Content-Type",
                "Value":"application/octet-stream"
            },
            {
                "Name" : "Dropbox-API-Arg",
                "Value" : "{\"path\":\"/test/test.pdf\", \"mode\":\"add\"}"
            }
            ]
      }
    ]
  },
  "ActivityId": "PlotToPDF"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**EDITED**
Either you can pass `Dropbox-API-Arg` header as below

```
"Name" : "Dropbox-API-Arg",
"Value" : "{\"path\":\"/test/test.pdf\", \"mode\":\"add\"}"
```

in the payload.

Or, passing `arg` url encoded string will also works.

Use following payload to work with Dropbox using Forge Design Automation.
You need to pass Arg parameter instead of ‘Dropbox-API-Arg’ header.

`arg={"path":"/result.pdf"}` encoded in URL as `"arg=%7B%22path%22%3A%22%2Fresult.pdf%22%7D"`

For example:

To post result.pdf in Dropbox.

```
{
    "Arguments": {
        "InputArguments": [
            {
                "Resource": "http://download.autodesk.com/us/samplefiles/acad/blocks_and_tables_-_metric.dwg",
                "Name": "HostDwg"
            }
        ],
        "OutputArguments": [
            {
                "Name": "Result",
                "HttpVerb": "POST",
                "Resource": "https://content.dropboxapi.com/2/files/upload?arg=%7B%22path%22%3A%22%2Fresult.pdf%22%7D",
                "StorageProvider": "Generic",
                "Headers": [
                    {
                        "Name":"Authorization",
                        "Value":"Bearer blahblahblah"
                    },
                    {"Name":"Content-Type",
                     "Value":"application/octet-stream"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    "ActivityId": "PlotToPDF"
}
```